# Illegal State Exception: Couldn't read row 0, col 1

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

This is probably such a simple fix, and I just can't see it.

I have a class which is used to create an entry into the sqlite table TRANSACTIONS. Part of this transaction creation includes inserting the borrower's name. To do this, I have a method which should get the user's name, by passing the user's B-Number as a parameter.

However, when I try to create the transaction, the app crashes and I am presented with the error

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
        at example.anna.com.pi_prototype_30.UsersDAO.cursorToUsers(UsersDAO.java:124)
        at example.anna.com.pi_prototype_30.UsersDAO.getUserName(UsersDAO.java:110)
        at example.anna.com.pi_prototype_30.BorrowScan$1.onClick(BorrowScan.java:118)
```

**CursorToUsers method:**

```
private Users cursorToUsers(Cursor cursor){
    Users user = new Users();

    user.setTableID(cursor.getLong(0));
    user.setuType(cursor.getString(1));
    user.setIdNum(cursor.getString(2));
    user.setName(cursor.getString(3));
    user.setEmail(cursor.getString(4));
    user.setCourse(cursor.getString(5));
    user.setPassword(cursor.getString(6));

    return user;
}
```

**getUserName Method**

```
public Users getUserName(String m) {

    Users user = null;
    String query = "SELECT name FROM  users WHERE id_number = ?";
    Cursor cursor = aDatabase.rawQuery(query, new String[]{m});
    //DatabaseUtils.dumpCurrentRow(c);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        user = cursorToUsers(cursor);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();
    return user;

}
```

**CreateLoan method**

```
public void addListenerOnCreateLoanButton(){
    final Context context = this;

    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.borrow_scan_create_loan);

    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Boolean didi = true;

            //Initialises today's date
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

            //Initialise loan variables
            String bNum = cardContentTxt.getText().toString();
            String kNum = contentTxt.getText().toString();
            String bDate = df.format(c.getTime());
            String rDate = "N/A";
            String type = "Loan";
            String bName = (usersDAO.getUserName(bNum)).toString();
            try {

                transDAO.open();
                transDAO.createTransactionEntry(type, bDate, rDate, bNum, bName, kNum);
                transDAO.close();

            }//try

            catch (Exception e) {
                didi = false;
                Log.d(TAG, "Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }//catch
            finally {
                if (didi) {
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(BorrowScan.this);
                    d.setTitle("Database write");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(BorrowScan.this);
                    tv.setText("it  worked ");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Created loan");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }//if
            }//finally
        }//onClick
    });//onClickListener
}//createLoan
```

The lines being flagged as causing the error are:

**Line 124:**

```
user.setuType(cursor.getString(1));
```

**Line 110:**

```
nameL = cursorToUsers(c);
```

**Line 118:**

```
String bName = (usersDAO.getUserName(bNum)).toString();
```

While I'm sure there is plenty I have done wrong, what is it that is causing this specific error?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: use `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor()` / `DatabaseUtils#dumpCurrentRow()` to see the columns in your `Cursor`

Comment: what do you think `SELECT 1` does?

Comment: good point @njzk2 ...

Comment: @pskink, where should I add that to my code?

Comment: where you have something like: Cursor cursor = ...; for example 'Cursor c = aDatabase.rawQuery'

Comment: @njzk2, shouldn't it be retrieving only 1 entry from the table? Id numbers (or bnumbers) are unique

Comment: use dumpCursor and you will see whats inside

Comment: @User588233 no. documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html (`1` is a literal value `expr` in the `result_column` definition). In your case, there really isn't much good reason to use `raw_query`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query only selects one column: `"SELECT name FROM  users WHERE id_number = ?"`

This means `cursor.getString(1)` in the `cursorToUsers()` method will throw an exception. Change `getUserName()` to this:

```
public Users getUserName(String m) {
    String name = null;
    String query = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE id_number = ?";
    Cursor cursor = aDatabase.rawQuery(query, new String[]{m});
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            name = cursor.getString(0);
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close()
    }
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know how your database is but try this select statement:

`SELECT * FROM  users WHERE id_number = ?`

Also, I would recommend specifying each column with it's names, like:

`SELECT ID,Type,IdNum,Name,Email,Course,Password FROM  users WHERE id_number = ?`

This avoids getting the wrong data. if you database changes.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I realised that my query was wrong. It should be SELECT name FROM users WHERE id_number =? However, I still have the same cursor issue as in my question

Comment: you are calling `c.moveToFirst()` two times. Try removing the first, also pay attention that it'll return false if the cursor is empty.
PS: Edit your question and update the SQL :)

Comment: I've edited my code in the question. It is still throwing up that error.